# assertThat returns() BigDecimal usingComparatorForType

Tags: assertj

I like to use `asserThat().returns()` combination to test the content of my objects. Unfortunately it does not work out of the box with BigDecimal because the equals method requires identical scale, which is not always the case. Instead the recommended way to assert `BigDecimal` is to use the `.compare()` method.
Consequently I tried to specify a comparator for BigDecimal type, but it is not taken into account as the following test fails:

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        assertThat(new BigDecimal("10.00"))
                .usingComparatorForType(BigDecimalComparator.BIG_DECIMAL_COMPARATOR, BigDecimal.class)
                .returns(BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::abs);
    }
```

I there a way to make the above test succeed, or is the only solution to use `isEqualByComparingTo()` which unfortunately breaks the nice chain of `.returns()`

```java
assertThat(frodo)
    .returns("Frodo", from(TolkienCharacter::getName))
    .returns(HOBBIT, from(TolkienCharacter::getRace));

assertThat(frodo.size()).isEqualByComparingTo(new BigDecimal("1.2300"))
```

Comment: `usingComparatorForType` is used in the context of field by field comparison like `isEqualToComparingFieldByField(Object)` it's not used in the `returns` context.

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#usingComparatorForType(java.util.Comparator,java.lang.Class)

Comment: @Maxime Dutaut the use case sounds reasonable so we've decided to improve the current implementation: https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 3.24.1, [`returns`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#returns(T,java.util.function.Function)) and [`doesNotReturn`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#doesNotReturn(T,java.util.function.Function)) honor comparators configured via [`usingComparatorForType`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#usingComparatorForType(java.util.Comparator,java.lang.Class)), so the original test should succeed:

```
@Test
void test() {
    assertThat(new BigDecimal("10.00"))
            .usingComparatorForType(BigDecimalComparator.BIG_DECIMAL_COMPARATOR, BigDecimal.class)
            .returns(BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::abs);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but only when I disabled `.usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, you still have a nice chain:

```
assertThat(frodo)
    .returns("Frodo", Frodo::getName)
    .matches(f -> f.getSize().compareTo(BigDecimal.TEN) == 0);
```